# Find the general solution of the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}+\tan x\tan y=\cos x\sec y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the differential equation

$\frac{dy}{dx}+\tan x\tan y=\cos x\sec y$

**My try**:

$\frac{dy}{dx}+\tan x\tan y=\cos x\sec y$

$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y}{\cos y}=\frac{\cos (x+y)}{\cos y}$

But I dont understand how to solve this differential equation
?

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use $$y=\sin ^{-1}(z)\implies y'=\frac{z'}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$ and simplify. If I am not mistaken, you should get something simple.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{dy}{dx}+\tan x\tan y=\cos x\sec y$

$or,\frac{dy}{\sec y~dx}+\tan x \sin y= \cos x$ //dividing both sides by secy;

$let \ v= \sin y;$

$\frac{dv}{dx}=\cos y \frac{dy}{dx}$ //differentiating both with respect to x;

$\frac{dv}{dx}= \frac{dy}{\sec y~dx}$

So, our equation to solve, is now simplified to;

$$
\frac{dv}{dx} + v \tan x= \cos x
$$
which  is simple  linear  differential  equation.
After solving for $v$, we can replace $v$ with $\sin y.$